# iFrame does not ALWAYS work (ssl certificate prevents it)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, iframe, youtube

I have two servers at Bluehost. One displays iframes with no trouble, the other one does not.

Here is the snippet working on server A:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="300" height="165" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QrzCRa6er8U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here is the snippet NOT working on server B:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="300" height="165" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QrzCRa6er8U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

As you can see, those lines are identical. Differences among servers: A is  cheaper and has no ssl. B is expensive (more capable) and has a Comodo ssl certificate.

Both work with Rails, Passenger and Apache. After 2 days of trying to solve this (first I took nginx from server B, in case it was that...) I am clueless. Does anyone have an idea why iframe does not work at B? I can paste any code or log needed.

(next test is to temporarily remove ssl, to check if that is the trouble)

Any help or question is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very very simple. Thanks to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571229/what-may-prevent-iframe-from-displaying-can-it-be-a-ssl-certificate) and its answer, now is working.

Problem was with certificate comodo, and the address. Instead of http, needs to be https. That it is.