# What may prevent iframe from displaying? Can it be a ssl certificate?

Tags: apache, ssl, iframe

I have 2 servers at Bluehost. One of them displays iframe with no trouble, the other one does not.

This is the code in both cases:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="300" height="165" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QrzCRa6er8U" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Both servers are vps. The one that does not work has an ssl certificate from comodo. Do I need special command for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change your IFRAME src to https instead of http.

Comment: So simple, so logical. Thank you very much Lisher.